# How do I pick a specific word out of a string with certain criteria?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I want to be able to locate a word of certain length (3 - 99 characters) that begins with a capital letter.
For example, in the following sentence (the actual sentence would be written and filled out by the user accordingly)

`My name is John and i am 20 years old.`

I want the word "John" to be picked, since it fits all the criteria.

Here is my code so far: (I know it's messy sorry I'm relatively new at this)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Name and age: ");
    string a = Console.ReadLine();
    string b = string.Empty;
    int val;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        if (Char.IsDigit(a[i]))
            b += a[i];
    }

    if (b.Length > 0)
        val = int.Parse(b);

    string inputStr = a;
    string outputStr = String.Concat(inputStr.Where(x => Char.IsUpper(x)));

    Console.WriteLine("Your name is " + outputStr);
    Console.WriteLine("You are " + b + " years old");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I'm tryin to get the program to tell me:

```
Your name is John
You are 20 years old
```

Iv'e gotten the program to tell me the age, but so far for the name i can only get it to give me capital letters (anywhere in the string)

Comment: well, what is it not doing?  what is it doing?  any errors?

Comment: Your code will become very uncompact they way you do it. I'd reccomend you use [Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) ([Regex Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-5.0)). You can easily create regexes with the [regexr](https://regexr.com/) website. Hope this helps

Comment: Picking out a word that consists of a single upper-case letter followed by any number of lower-case letters is easy.  Parsing English enough to read a paragraph and get your program to figure out someone's name and age is a much more _interesting_ problem

Answer (score 1):

You can split first your sentence into words, then select the word starting with capital letters (provided they are separated by spaces)

```cs
      int minLength = 3;
      int maxLength = 99;
      string[] CapWords = inputStr.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                            .Where(x =>  char.IsUpper(x[0])&& x.Length>= minLength && x.Length <= maxLength)
                                            .ToArray<string>();

     string outputStr = CapWords[1];
```

Actually, it will only work if the first word in your sentence starts by a capital letter but it is not the name, and then the second word starting by a capital letter is the name you are looking for.

Comment: Add the Length check as well.

Answer (score 1):

This might be overkill for what you want to do, but usually Regex (Regular Expressions)
are a great way to parse strings:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

            string pattern = @"(?!^)\b[A-Z][a-z]{2,98}\b";
            string input = "My name is John and i am 20 years old.";
            string output = Regex.Match(input, pattern).Value;
```

[Regexr](https://regexr.com/) is a great tool for creating those.

Comment: Your `{3,98}` should be `{2,98}`.  You won't pick up three character words the way you have it now

Comment: @Flydog57 thanks for finding that, fixed it ;-)